Flutter detect when DraggableScrollableSheet is scrolled down
I have this UI here:

When the keyboard is up, I've made it so that the bottom sheet goes to the top. When the user types, results will show up on that bottom sheet. A really nice touch for the UI would be the ability to swipe down on the thumb of the sheet and for the keyboard to close. Right now, when you pull the sheet all the way down, it is bounded by the keyboard.
I need to be able to flick down on the sheet and have the keyboard dismiss.
I'm using a DraggableScrollableSheet:
final bottomSheetScrollController = DraggableScrollableController();
DraggableScrollableSheet(
    initialChildSize: 0.19,
    minChildSize: 0.19,
    controller: bottomSheetScrollController,
    builder: (context, scrollController) {
       return Container(...
    }

and inside initState I tried creating a callback to handle this:
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    bottomSheetScrollController.addListener(() {
        // if the scroll sheet's size is small again, then unfocus the keyboard. 
        if(bottomSheetController.size < 0.3) {
           FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
        }
    });
  }

This isn't working, since the initial child size of the DraggableScrollableSheet is 0.19. When the text box is clicked, it programmatically uses animateTo to make the scrollSheet extend to the top. But since the addListener callback is watching for when the size is less than 0.3, it will constantly be called. It will pull the sheet right back down if I try to pull up on it, since at the start it's initial size is 0.19, which is less than 0.3. I also tried this solution and couldn't get good results.
How can I make it so that when the bottom sheet is scrolled down to the bottom when the keyboard is open, it will make the keyboard close?

Don't know why I didn't think of this earlier, but in my case what worked was just checking if the search box's FocusNode.hasFocus as equal to true before manually calling animateTo.
if (currentSize < 0.2 && searchBoxFocusNode.hasFocus) {
    bottomSheetScrollController.animateTo(0.17,
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
              curve: Curves.easeInOut);
    FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
}

